# Getting SQL Server CLR "Create Assembly" location from within the DLL itself

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr

The assembly is stored in the database, and you can get the registered location like this:

```sql
SELECT af.name FROM sys.assemblies a
INNER JOIN sys.assembly_files af
        ON a.assembly_id = af.assembly_id
WHERE a.name = 'MyAssemblyName'
```

However, I'd like to get it without asking SQL Server and I'd like to get it from within the running assembly. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` returns blank. `AppDomain.Current.BaseDirectory` returns the binn path of SQL Server.

When I registered the assembly with `CREATE ASSEMBLY`, I gave it a path. I'd like to get that path.

**EDIT (SOLUTION)**

I had to consult the database server after all. But it's not so bad because at least the connection string is not hard coded.

```cs
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]
public static SqlString AssemblyLocation()
{
  using (var connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
  {
    var cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT af.name FROM sys.assemblies a INNER JOIN sys.assembly_files af ON a.assembly_id = af.assembly_id WHERE a.name = '{AssemblyName().Value}'", connection);
    connection.Open();
    return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
  }
}

[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]
public static SqlString AssemblyName()
{
  return typeof(StoredProcedures).Assembly.GetName().Name;
}

[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]
public static SqlString WebApiRoot()
{
  var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(AssemblyLocation().Value);
  return config.AppSettings.Settings["WebApiRoot"].Value;
}
```

Comment: I found the answer that explained that assembly's are added to the database and they do not have a path.  I was trying to work out why an assembly was not working, and one of the options was that it could not be found hence look for the path.  The other was security, which was the actual problem.  Once I knew that the assembly was loaded into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments in the other answer, it sounds like you want a context connection. From the examples in the documentation:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true")
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I registered the assembly with `CREATE ASSEMBLY`, I gave it a path. I'd like to get that path.

This is not possible as that path was only used to read the Assembly into the database. The `content` column that you see in `sys.assembly_files` *is* the Assembly  / DLL. It physically exists in the database now. That is what `CREATE ASSEMBLY` does. This is a benefit over the old Extended Stored Procedure (XPs) framework as there are no external dependencies; when you back up the database, the Assembly is backed up with it as the data resides in the database, not on the file system.

Comment: Then is there something I can call to get the instance of sql server I'm in so I don't have to hard code that or get it from a config? Getting a conn string from a Config would be chasing my tail b/c the whole point of getting the path was accessing a config file for the dll. Thanks.

Comment: @toddmo: from the examples in the documentation: `SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true")`.

Comment: @BenThul, that did it. Can you add an answer?

Comment: @toddmo What? Your question never said anything even close to "config file". If that is the goal, why wouldn't you mention that? There could very well be a better overall solution than using a config file for a DLL that isn't being used and a path that need not exist.

Comment: There isn't a better solution to using a configuration file though. I needed that path.